# i have an error(s), it's not working, which are the errors

Tags: json, actionscript-3, flash, phpmyadmin

```
package  {

import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.*;
import com.adobe.serialization.json.*;

public class ScreenCategories extends Sprite {

    public var myLoader:URLLoader;
    public var filePath:String;
    public var myReq:URLRequest;

    public function ScreenCategories() {
        // constructor code
        reLoad();
    }

    // Constructor: Create an array of three categories
    public function reLoad()
    {

        lastButtonEndedY = 35;

        /* 
            In our real app, we would load in the categories from our database (via a JSON)
            Hint: Saving the Objects into the array at the index that equals the ID is advised
        */
        filePath = "getCategories.php"; //declare path and file name
        myReq = new URLRequest(filePath); //create URLRequest to access the file

        myLoader = new URLLoader(); //create URLLoader to load the file

        //add event listener to run fileLoaded function when loading is complete
        myLoader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);
        myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);

        //add event listener to listen for any error thrown during loading process
        myLoader.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
        myLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);

        myLoader.load(myReq); //start loading a file with our URLLoader instance
    }

    //loading complere so print content of a text file to our Text Field
    function loadComplete(e:Event):void
    {
        var jsonstring:String = myLoader.data; 
        var categories:Array = JSON.decode(jsonstring);

        for (var count:int = 0; count < categories.length; count++) {
            var aCategory:Object = category[count];
            trace(aCategory.categoryname);
            trace(aCategory.categoryid);
        }

        ///////////////
        // Consider that it would be more responsible to add these to an array and maintain 
        // which are being added/deleted, then we could create a print function!
        ///////////////
    }

    //if any error was thrown, event was also dispatched and now you can print
    //the error description to the text field.
    public function ioErrorHandler(e:IOErrorEvent):void
    {
         trace("There was a problem loading "+filePath+": "+e);
    }

}
```

}

```
        // for each "category" in our list (Array)...
        for (var count in categories)
        {
            // Create a button for each of the categories that exist in our Array
            var aCategory:BtnCategory = new BtnCategory(categories[count].category);

            // Add the BtnCategory to the stage
            aCategory.x = 0;
            aCategory.y = lastButtonEndedY;
            aCategory.name = categories[count].id; // give it a unique name!
            addChild(aCategory);

            lastButtonEndedY += (aCategory.getHeight() + 1);
        }

        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClicked);
```

This is supposed to work on Action script 3 for a mobile app where i need a category list that will take me to a product list and the a product.... but i'm working first on the category list where the values are read from JSON, i already have a getCategory.php document where my json was returned correctly..... but when i run the swf it says error....

Comment: Do you mean that one of your error handlers fires, or is there another error that you are seeing?

Comment: no.... the swf doesn't run cuz it says this code has errors... but i don't know where the errors are..... i don't know if i wrote something wrong or if i'm missing something.... i'm new to coding so i can't tell if this is right or wrong

Comment: It sounds like there is no error (otherwise you'd see it) and instead what you mean is that the SWF just isn't functioning as expect it?

Comment: flash says there's an error on:
    function loadComplete(e:Event):void
and:
    public function ioErrorHandler(e:IOErrorEvent):void

Comment: i erased 

        public function ioErrorHandler(e:IOErrorEvent):void

Comment: but i still have problems with:   function loadComplete(e:Event):void

Comment: Copy the error and paste it into the body of your post

Comment: type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it looks like `filePath = "getCategories.php";` is your problem.
When you run locally or in your dev environment it will look for that php page in the same directory that the SWF is in which will probably work fine for you. But when you publish to a phone that is no longer the location of the php page.
As such you will probably get the IO error since the server does not exist.

[EDIT]
Well now that you finally posted the error I can see what your issue is.

```
type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Event
```

Is stating that it can not find the Event class.
Looking at your code you are not importing it either.
The closest you come to it is the MouseEvent.
So instead of just importing the MouseEvent try this.

```
import flash.events.*;
```

Comment: i agree.... but it's not the case cuz it's just a homework mocking a mobile app

Comment: Ok now that you actually posted the error in a comment I see your problem and I edited my answer for you.

Comment: k.... that error was fixed apparently, but other errors came out after :.(

Comment: @RominaMora Well progress is good. If this fixed the particular issue then you need to flag this as correct so others do not try to post other solutions. And you can always start a new question with your new issues.